# Turn PHP Program with MySQL Database into .exe file

Tags: php, mysql, database, exe

So I have this php program that I can run on my computer locally using WAMP. However, I would want it to be accessed by another person  in his own computer. Some of the things I've read include dealing with the IP address. However, in my specific situation, I think it would be better to turn it into an executable file (php + the mysql database I used).

Is it possible? If yes, how? 
If not, what is the best or easiest way for it to be accessed by, for example, a client.

Comment: XY Problem in the making

Comment: The best you can hope for is packaging this up as an appliance you can deploy as a virtual machine through something like VirtualBox, VMWare or otherwise. What you're talking about is usually a world of hurt unless you have some control over the target environment.

Answer (score 1):

There is no .exe natively with PHP.  PHP does support PHAR archives that are executable and you can use an SQLite database which is portable.

This is what you will see with applications like Composer.

http://php.net/manual/en/intro.phar.php

Answer (score 0):

just create an executable program with vb or something, then connect it to the database,,,